# Export remote server Postgres table to CSV file on local machine in rails and postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have read-only access to a database on a remote server. So, I can execute:

```
\COPY (select numbers from shipments TO '/tmp/shipment.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

but when i do this the shipment.csv file gets saved in the server. Is there any procedure of saving that csv file in my local instead of the server ??

Comment: You can see the way resolve your problem at here:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/36252

Comment: There is a closing parenthesis `)` missing after shipments.